# OPA masking a dynamic array field

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I'm trying to apply masking on an input and result field that is part of an array. And the size of the array is dynamic. Based on the documentation, it is instructed to provide absolute array index which is not possible in this use case. Do we have any alternative?

Eg. If one needs to mask the age field of all the students from the input document?

***Input:***

```
"students" : [
  {
    "name": "Student 1",
    "major": "Math",
    "age": "18"
  },
  {
    "name": "Student 2",
    "major": "Science",
    "age": "20"
  },
  {
    "name": "Student 3",
    "major": "Entrepreneurship",
    "age": "25"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just generate a copy of `input` that has a field (or set of fields) removed from the `input`, you can use `json.remove`. The trick is to use a comprehension to compute the list of paths to remove. For example:

```
paths_to_remove := [sprintf("/students/%v/age", [x]) | some x; input.students[x]]
result := json.remove(input, paths_to_remove)
```

If you are trying to mask fields from the `input` document in the decision log using the [Decision Log Masking](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/management-decision-logs/#masking-sensitive-data) feature then you would write something like:

```
package system.log

mask[x] {
    some i
    input.input.students[i]
    x := sprintf("/input/students/%v/age", [i])
}
```

Comment: So, to leverage the masking capability, we might have to iterate over the input multiple again. If there is either a time sensitive application or an application that processes huge payload then this makes me think if it would be efficient to include the masking logic while one iterates through the input for policy decisioning itself. Does that sound reasonable?